# How to remove duplicates rows in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I need to remove the perfect duplicates rows in loop when I use itertuples in jinja2:

```
{% for rows in df.itertuples() %}
    {% set value = rows['value'] %}
    {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

at the end of loop, I have a duplicates value like:

```
123 
456
123
456
123
456
```

I need to remove the duplicates but I don't found the solution
Do you have an idea?

The result I want is:

```
123
456
```

Comment: If you have control over the source data going into `df`, the pre-processing should be done there, before it gets to Jinja in the web template.  The data should be cleaned/processed by the back-end, and displayed by the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code to drop duplicates in df:

```
{% for rows in df.drop_duplicates().itertuples() %}
    {% set value = rows['value'] %}
    {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's a link to the documentation for drop_duplicates():
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Output:

```
123
456
```